# Exchange: Messages that were delayed for several hours arrive all at once

Tags: exchange

One of our clients has sent messages in his organization, and none of them were received. Then she sent a 'check' message and it arrived together with all the delayed messages.

What can be the cause of it?

Update:
It was caused by space shortage on the partition, which in term was caused by Hyper-V bug that shrinks the 'expanding' Virtual HD to the size of it's content. I restarted the server and the VHD returned to it's original size. To prevent similar errors I converted the 'expanding' VHD to 'fixed' VHD.

Everything runs normally now. Thanks.

Comment: What have you checked so far? What is in the logs? What is in the headers? etc., etc.

Comment: I have checked the logs, but immediately the problem made itself obvious, read the update.

Comment: it's perfectly acceptable (and recommended) to post your solution as an answer to this question. You can then gain upvotes on it and mark it accepted, so the system doesn't randomly bump it to the top of the home page in a few months time.

Comment: do as Ben suggests and post your solution as an answer. I believe it may help others with the same problem. It's important when asking such questions to give some indication of what steps you have already taken to diagnose the problem, otherwise they're likely to get closed, or at least downvoted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was caused by space shortage on the partition, which in term was caused by Hyper-V bug that shrinks the 'expanding' Virtual HD to the size of it's content. I restarted the server and the VHD returned to it's original size. To prevent similar errors I converted the 'expanding' VHD to 'fixed' VHD.

Answer (score 1):

This could be due to any number of factors, anywhere along the way between her mail client and the recipient's. This would include their mail system, yours, any spam filters or gateways in between, and any relays the messages are passing through.

What version of Exchange are you using? Do you know what mail system they are using? You will need to do a message trace to see what happened along the way. Although it could have been a synchronisation issue with their mail client, and the 'check' message could have triggered a send/receive. Has anyone else been affected by this issue?

Comment: Read the update please

Answer (score 1):

I have seen this happen due to improper firewall rules between the exchange server and the client. Normally the server sends a notification to the client when new mail has arrived, causing the client to go download new messages. If this notofication packet is blocked, the behavior you described can happen.